# SAML Authentication (How does the browser know)

Tags: session, cookies, saml, adfs, servicenow

SAML tokens are used for me to login to my app.

I go to app page, and then redirected through adfs, then logged into the app.

Theres no issue with logging in. What im wondering is, lets say i close the browser and re-open it, i can still get to the app. This is expected, but i want to know how the app knows im still logged in. Is there some sort of session cookie stored in my browser which the app reads?

The app im using is servicenow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Depending on the framework, the apps can set session state via cookies. Typically these are session cookies, but it is possible that the browser process was not fully flushed and so session cookies look persistent. We've also seen apps set persistent cookies.